# Handle camunda start process errors

Tags: camunda

I have a process that fails on the first task because of data validation. I want the task to fail. My problem is that when I start the Camunda process with the REST API I receive an HTML page produced by the underlying Tomcat. How can I get a comprehensive JSON response from the API instead of an HTML ?

I'm running Camunda CE 7.9.
I'm deploying a spring boot war on the Camunda Tomcat provided by Camunda.

Response:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <title>État HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        [...]
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>État HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error</h1>
    <hr class="line" />
    <p><b>Type</b> Rapport d''exception</p>
    <p><b>message</b> company.service.RestException: message: Agent XXX not found</p>
    <p><b>description</b> Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l''a empêché de satisfaire la requête.</p>
    <p><b>exception</b></p>
    <pre>org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: company.service.RestException: message: Agent XXX not found
[...]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You were most likely using the wrong endpoint URL.